# Spine.js has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spine.js

I'm still wrapping my head around [Spine JS](http://spinejs.com), its really clever cool stuff. I see it has support for [Model Relationships](http://spinejs.com/docs/relations) but I can't seem to find any information about `has_many :through` relationships.

I'm guessing its not possible, does anyone know if it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Half a decade late, but Spine.js does not have a `has_many` relation.

Quoting the [source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spine/spine/master/lib/relation.js), it only has belongsTo, hasOne and hasMany:

```
  Spine.Model.extend({
    hasMany: function(name, model, fkey) {
      if (fkey == null) {
        fkey = (underscore(this.className)) + "_id";
      }
      return this.prototype[name] = function(value) {
        return association(name, model, this, fkey, Collection).refresh(value);
      };
    },
    belongsTo: function(name, model, fkey) {
      if (fkey == null) {
        fkey = (underscore(singularize(name))) + "_id";
      }
      this.prototype[name] = function(value) {
        return association(name, model, this, fkey, Instance).update(value).find();
      };
      return this.attributes.push(fkey);
    },
    hasOne: function(name, model, fkey) {
      if (fkey == null) {
        fkey = (underscore(this.className)) + "_id";
      }
      return this.prototype[name] = function(value) {
        return association(name, model, this, fkey, Singleton).update(value).find();
      };
    }
  });
```